# ¿Cómo obtener valor de los comandos y asignarlos a una variable en shell scritp?

Tags: shell

Cuando ejecuto este script desde la línea de comando y le paso los argumentos, no obtengo ningún resultado. Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto los comandos contenidos en la $CPU , puedo obtener resultados.

¿Cómo se pueden tomar los resultados de un comando que debe ejecutarse dentro de un script, guardarlo en una variable y luego mostrar esa variable en la pantalla?

```
elif    [ $num -eq 1 ]; then
    cpu=$(top | awk 'NR == 3 { print $8 }') 
    echo "el valor del cpu es: $cpu"
```

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, No has dado una explicación exacta de tu situación o problema, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿`top | awk 'NR == 3 { print $8 }'` te devuelve valores? Me extraña... porque es un comando que no "para". ¿Tal vez con `top -b -n1`?

Comment: el top | awk 'NR == 3 { print $8 }  me devuelve el NI del cpu

Answer (score 0):

Se quedaba iterando por el cual no me dejaba acceder la solución fue la siguiente:

```
 elif    [ $num -eq 1 ]; then
    cpu=$(top -n 1 | awk 'NR == 3 { print $8 }') 
    echo "el valor del cpu es: $cpu"
```

La cual  -n 1 solo itera una vez y con este puedo acceder al código